# Extract from txt file python

Tags: python

I extracted lines from txt.file skipping first couple lines due to comments. After doing this I have group of lists. How can I get only the values of first indexes and append it into new list?

```
['364.00', '0.000', '0.000', '364.00', '28.00', '28.00', '0.00', '0.00']
```

`['450.00', '0.000', '360.000', '450.00', '28.00', '28.00', '0.00', '0.00']
['590.00', '0.000', '360.000', '590.00', '28.00', '28.00', '0.00', '0.00']`

Thanks for help.

Comment: What you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "group of lists"? For a list of lists it could be done like that:

```
lists = [['450.00', '0.000', '360.000', '450.00', '28.00', '28.00', '0.00', '0.00'],
['590.00', '0.000', '360.000', '590.00', '28.00', '28.00', '0.00', '0.00']]

first_entries = [i[0] for i in lists]

print(first_entries)
```

Output:
`['450.00', '590.00']`